# Systemd output in Docker without -t switch

Tags: shell, docker, systemd

When Docker image is started in terminal mode like:

```
docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --entrypoint '/bin/bash' -it jrei/systemd-debian:10
```

and then manually entered:

```
exec /lib/systemd/systemd
```

systemd displays the init log like:

```
ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
Detected virtualization docker.
Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)!

Set hostname to <e9366e98a874>.
File /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service:12 configures an IP firewall (IPAddressDeny=any), but the local system does not support BPF/cgroup based firewalling.
Proceeding WITHOUT firewalling in effect! (This warning is only shown for the first loaded unit using IP firewalling.)
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
[  OK  ] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Create System Users...
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
....
```

When Docker image is started in WITHOUT terminal mode like:

```
docker run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/run/lock -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --entrypoint '/bin/bash' jrei/systemd-debian:10 -c "exec /lib/systemd/systemd"
```

systemd displays no output. I can not use the `-t` or `-i` switch as the docker command is hardwired in the command executor I am using. How should the command above be modified to start the systemd with output and still with PID 1 (wth `exec` directly from the entry shell) but without the `-t` Docker tty switch?

Comment: My recommendation would be to avoid systemd in Docker at all costs.  For example, if you look at the `OK` things in your sample output, you want _none_ of those things in Docker.  General practice is to just run some single application in a container without an init system, or maybe with something extremely minimal like `tini`.

Comment: I need it to test Ansible roles which uses systemctl a lot. I have everything working the only thing remaining is how to emulate the `-t` switch.

Comment: A virtual machine is probably a better fit for this use case, since a Docker container typically runs only a single process and doesn’t have things like an sshd or its own network stack.

Comment: I understand that it is atypical. With systemd started with `-t` switch I have it fully working incl. sshd service. I just need to know how to create a fake tty so that the systemd will think that it was started with `-t` witch and will display its output.